# how to show the hidden text after select a value from select Box?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

### .html

```
<div class="column">
      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Subject</mat-label>
          <mat-select formControlName="Subject">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let Subject of Subjects" [value]="Subject.value">
              {{Subject.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Grade</mat-label>
          <mat-select formControlName="Grade">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let Grade of Grades" [value]="Grade.value">
              {{Grade.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Type</mat-label>
          <mat-select formControlName="Type">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let Type of Types" [value]="Type.value">
              {{Type.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
```

//label is here

```
<div [hidden] =  "showLable() === true ? false: true">
  <p >Maximum Price exceeding</p> 
</div>
```

### .ts

```
export class NewLectureComponent implements OnInit {
  isNotify: boolean;

      showLable(){
         this.isNotify = true;
      }
}
```

- I want to show the label **subject, grade , type** this angular material select boxes after filled!
- when i filled subject grade type these fields label want to show

Comment: Can you please clarify/elaborate it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **ngIf** Directive that can be used to show or hide the html elements when required.

```
<div *ngIf="isNotify">
  <p >Maximum Price exceeding</p> 
</div>
```

So when the isNotify value will be true the html element would be added into the doucument if false it would be added as a binding(a template).

Comment: Thank you for your try. But when i select one value of select box in .ts component want to identify that value and show the hidden text

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code,To how to show the hidden text after select a value from select Box?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Elements Using Select Box</title>
<style>
    .box{
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #228B22; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option>Choose Color</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this code will be useful.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your try. Anyway there is some idea about also.But I expected angular component answer.